# What should I do with "exploding" bottles?

Tags: carbonation, techniques, first-time-brewer, bottle-bomb

I have a case (11 bottles with caps + 1 splash on the wall) of podpiwek and I'm slightly pissed at this moment. The instructions on the box said to fill the bottles to 3/4 of the volume and no more and after an incident with overfilled bottles of kvass I measured everything to the milliliter this time. Today it turned out that 3/4 is way too much - the podpiwek didn't even foam, it was in the bottle one moment and on the wall the next.

Can I somehow still drink this - open the bottle without the content exploding out of it and catching the content somehow? I don't want to open it cap-down, because I'm 100% sure it will knock the bottle out of my hand and whatever vessel I use to catch the drink, I'm sure it will just splash back up when pouring that way.

PS.

While writing this question I realized I used twice the amount of sugar and yeast I should have used. Not counting the podpiwek mix (that's there only for flavour), I have 5L of water, flat teaspoon of dry baking yeast and 600g of sugar. It was prepared and bottled on the same day, on the Sunday evening (11 Jun). Should I be terrified?

Comment: Twice the amount of sugar ? You have bombs, get rid of them ! Also lower the temperature as possible so the pressure will also be as low as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I did (and I'm writing this happy, with a glass of podpivek in hand):

1. I put all the bottles into the fridge as soon as I got the chance to do so. I put on best improvised PPE I could find in the house just in case one of the bottle was ready to explode.
2. I bought a freezer with fast delivery option ;p
3. I put one bottle of podpivek in the freezer for 20 min as a test, to make sure it doesn't freeze and break the bottle or it doesn't pop in the freezer.
4. I went to the bathroom, PPE on, and carefully tried to open very cold bottle, hoping for a gusher instead of an instant evacuation from the bottle. I've dealt with a fountain in a bottle before and I can catch all/most of it.
5. As I pry the cap open, I hear a hiss. Instead of opening the bottle right away, I pry the cap as long as there is a sound comming from the bottle. Bubbles build up in the bottle from time to time, but I need to only flip the bottle to get rid of them. For the most of the time I can just hold a bottle and bubbles don't form, so I'm just holding it in one position, waiting for the gas to evacuate.
6. Eventually, the sound stops and as I reseal the bottle and unseal it again, I only hear a slight pop instead of a hiss. When I open a bottle, it's perfectly peacefull, not even a foam forming up.

I plan to do this with all of the bottles over the weekend and I'd guess that as long as I keep them in the fridge, they will be safe to open without sprying their content everywhere.

Comment: The freezer step was not necessary, I degassed all the bottles at once stright from the fridge.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 - be careful.  Whatever you, do it with goggles and gloves on.  Exploding bottles are no joke.

You could try to open them and drink them.  They may be extra yeastie and carbonated and probably not worth the risk/effort.  Do it in a sink over a large salad bowl to catch it all.

Best bet is to throw a towel over the top of all of them, and pop the cap on them all and clean up the mess.

Or, you can shoot the bottles with a pellet gun from a safe distance (controlled detonation).

Carbonating in the bottle is such a hassle.  Do yourself a favor and splurge on some kegging equipment.  So much easier...

Comment: Do I need to open them as soon as possible or will the yeast become inactive after running out of oxygen?

Comment: THe yeast will eventually die off (run out of sugar), but why put it off?  The batch will likely not be very good, if you try to salvage it.  In the meantime, you have a potential hazard sitting around.